# Elastic Beanstalk and Worker Tier? (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron

I'm trying to setup my app that's hosted on EB with a worker that will run some basic cron jobs to feed an RDS database with data that the app consumes.

I deployed this `cron.yaml`at first:

```
version: 1
cron:
  - name: "count"
    url: "/api/dostuff"
    schedule: "* * * * *"
  - name: "fetch"
    url: "/api/dootherstuff"
    schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
```

Which gave me a worker with severe health problems

```
100.0 % of the requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx.
```

Logging onto my worker ec2 instance I noticed this in my access_log

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [23/May/2016:08:54:13 +0000] "POST /api/dostuff HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

So apparently it did not find the endpoints. I was under the impression that the worker interfaces with my main app and tries to poll that. But I might be wrong?

Any way, to further test stuff I took out `/api/dostuff` and `/api/dootherstuff` from the main app and deployed it together with the worker tier. As it is now, health shows up as green on the EB dashboard, which is good.

But when I check my RDS (by the way, I put the worker tier in the same security group as my RDS, and same VPC aswell). It has not populated the DB with new data.
So I logged on the instances and checked access_log which is filled with

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [23/May/2016:09:53:41 +0000] "POST /api/dostuff HTTP/1.1" 301 235 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

I mean, it's polling every second with this stuff.

If I check SQS, there's not much happening there
[image]

I setup the WorkerQueue to Maximum Receives of 1000 as I don't need the Dead Letter Thing.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I get my cron jobs properly setup?